# How to create StackView with width = largest child's width on iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uistackview

I want to place label to the bottom of image and align them vertically. I've tried to use `StackView` to achieve this. And I get this:

[image]

Is there any way to show all label's text correctly? Label text can have any length.

Answer (score 3):

- Constrain the label and the stack view to have equal widths.
- Set the horizontal content hugging priority of the label to 249 (so it can get wider if it's narrower than the image).
- Set the horizontal content compression resistance of the label to 751 (so it forces the stack view to be wider if necessary).

[image: constraints]

Result:

[image: resulting layout]

Comment: How it would work if the label is smaller than image?

Comment: Then the label will be aligned according to its text alignment setting. Try it and see.

Comment: All those red lines around your views are constraints that aren't satisfied. Choose Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > All Views > Update Frames. Also, the red arrow next to the scene name in the outline means there are errors or missing constraints. Click the arrow to get a list of the problems.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fix the width of `stackview`.

Change the **Alignment** property of `stackview` to **Center**.

[image]

The label will grow itself with the text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Irfan! This answer should be the accepted solution.